# Prevent Windows 7 from unpluging External HDD

Tags: windows, windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

I have installed Windows 7 as my media server. I pluged in 500GB external HDD via USB. I have changed power plan to Best Performance and changed advenced power settings to never turn off HDD etc. I even yesterday wrote powershell script (create and delete folder on this disk) and I have added it to harmonogram to run every 5 minutes starting from system boot. And nothing! Disk after some time (I realy can't say when) is turning off and Windows show "Unknown Device" in Device Manager. Then only system reboot or disk reboot helps.

Any ideas how to prevent Windows 7 from stopping my external HDD?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Usually when Windows unplugs an USB device, it doesn't mark it as an "Unknown Device", instead it just disappears from the Device Manager.

I'm afraid you might have a hardware (probably the USB-(S)ATA bridge) problem, not a software one.

Are there any entries in the Event Log? You might look into the [USB Event Tracing For Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463163) whitepaper for tips how to debug this.